# Erro ao tentar migrar bd do Laravel para PostgreSQL

Tags: laravel, postgresql

Estou utilizando o PostgreSQL "5.4.*"

Utilizando o MySQL, após o `php artisan migrate` tdo ok.

Porém agora preciso utilizar o PostgreSQL no projeto, porém após mudar o DB:

```
DB_CONNECTION=pgsql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=5432
DB_DATABASE=laravel-api
DB_USERNAME=postgres
DB_PASSWORD=1234
```

Me da este erro:

```
D:\wamp64\www\laravel\laravel-api>php artisan migrate

  [Illuminate\Database\QueryException]
  could not find driver (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = public and table_name = migrations)


  [PDOException]
  could not find driver
```

Detalhe, o ambiente é Windows.

Comment: Habilitou a extensão para o postgres no php.ini?

Comment: Coloque o arquivo de configuração do banco de dados `database.php` completo.

Comment: Estou utilizando o PostgreSQL "5.4.*" --> Não existe tal versão do PostgreSQL. A mais recente é a 11.1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Para habilitar a extensão do PDO para postgres no PHP, o primeiro passo é encontar a seguinte linha no php.ini e remover o `;`

```
;extension=php_pdo_pgsql.dll
```

Depois reinicie o apache. Pode verificar se a instalação ocorreu corretamente com o `phpinfo()`, deve mostrar algo como:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Outra forma de ver quais drivers do PDO estão instalados é chamar método estatico [`PDO::getAvailableDrivers()`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.getavailabledrivers.php)

```
<?php
echo "<pre>";
print_r(PDO::getAvailableDrivers());
```

Saída:

```
Array
(
    [0] => mysql
    [1] => pgsql
    [2] => sqlite
)
```

Comment: Vlw, funcionou!