# The pgsql driver is not currently installed

Tags: php, postgresql, zend, zend-framework-2

Estou utilizando o `WampServer` com o `Postgres` instalado na minha maquina local e quando vou acessar a aplicação ocorre o erro abaixo:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend_Db_Adapter_Exception' with message 'The pgsql driver is not currently installed' in ...

No php.ini do apache e do php já esta instalo o modulo abaixo

```
extension=php_pdo_pgsql.dll
```

Porém mesmo assim ocorre o mesmo erro?

Comment: `extension=php_pdo_pgsql.dll` esse é o módulo PDO para Postgres, tem que instalar o modulo `extension=php_pgsql.dll`

Comment: já esta instalado o mudulo  extension=php_pgsql.dll

Comment: Faz uma pagina de phpinfo() e verifique se o modulo foi carregado?

Comment: não mostra o modulo php_pgsql.dll no phpinfo

Comment: `extension=php_pgsql.dll` e `extension=php_pdo_pgsql.dll` não aparece PostgreSQL Support no phpinfo?

Comment: Verificou se na pasta `ext` do wamp existem essas duas dll? acredito que tenha feita o [processo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/246914/91) corretamente.

Comment: não existe essa pasta

Comment: Alguma outra dica ?

Comment: Deve ter uma pasta na instalação do wamp com essas dlls